# GUID like identifier which contains non hexadecimal letters

Tags: guid, typeform

I've developped a business system which is connected to an external Typeform via a webhook. Until recently, every webhook request sent by the API was authentified with a token string, which I could parse to a GUID. This was really helpful for reusing it into the system.

A few days ago, the identification token format changed to something like :

```
pvv25szf6ejrdyz3vdgpvv9w37u9t0at
```

which is obviously not a GUID (non hexa letters).

Is there any *extended GUID* format/norm that I am not aware of and which could generate this kind of string? Or is this just a random string, nothing more, nothing less?

Thanks!

Comment: This is impossible for us to guess what that string represents. I suggest you talk to the developers of the app that supplies it. Or just use strings locally, it's a safer option for the long term.

Comment: A GUID is a **G**lobal **U**nique **ID**entifier, there is no GUID format. The only limitation a GUID has is that it is ["a 128-bit number used to identify information in computer systems"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier)

Comment: Turns out, in the eyes of MS, a GUID does actually a defined format. For more info [read this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa373931(v%3Dvs.80))

Comment: @MindSwipe I come from the MS World, this may explain why  So, from your knowledge, there is no (put whatever you want here) number/string used to identify information in a computer system which could match the string I get?

Comment: @DavidG already tried. No answer so far, my guess is that I can reach them here more efficiently than with their own marketing-oriented ticket system. Point taken for the use of string instead of GUIDs for the long term, it makes sense.